# Programmatic MSBuild Recursive Copy with wildcards

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am creating an MSBuild v4 task that happens to need to call the Copy task to recursively copy some files (without flattening the directory structure at the destination).

I have come up with:

```
var copy = new Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy
{
    BuildEngine = this.BuildEngine,
    SourceFiles = new ITaskItem[] { new TaskItem(@"C:\source\**\*.foo") },
    DestinationFolder = new TaskItem(@"c:\dest\\")
};
copy.Execute();
```

but am getting an error 'Could not copy C:\source\**\*.foo to c:\dest\* - Illegal characters in path'

There doesn't seem to be much online help for pragmatic invocation, and have drawn a blank.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Jon

Comment: If that had worked i think it would have flattened your folder structure is that what you want?

Comment: No, I want c:\source\a\b\c.foo to copy to c:\dest\a\b\c.foo - Thanks, I'll update the question

Comment: would it help if you remove the double \\ in c:\dest\ ?

Comment: the double dest was the resolved values of %(RecursiveDir), as seen by the Copy task, although I did play around with a number of permutations of slash

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like the Copy task doesn't have an intrinsic understanding of recursion; the following code would cause the Copy task to be invoked once per file level, and this is handled by the MSBuild runner.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <x Include="c:\source\**\*.foo" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(x)" DestinationFolder="c:\dest\%(RecursiveDir)" />
```

However, since the Copy task seems to treat SourceFiles and DestinationFiles as an associative array (each of type ITaskItem[]), we just performed a recursive descent and built up these two arrays manually, before execing it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, when writing the same thing in XML, you wouldn't have passed the path with wildcards directly to the `SourceFiles` property. You would've created an `ItemGroup` and *then* you pass that to your task.

As far as I know, it's the `ItemGroup` does the wildcard magic, so in C# it's up to you to manually create the array of `ITaskItem` that contains the complete list of items that you want to copy.

If you can, create an `ItemGroup` that you pass to your task, which in turn passes it to `Copy`.

Comment: It is the ItemGroup (or at least MSBuild) that does the expansion, and this causes the Copy task to be called once per directory

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply using MSBuild Copy task. You don't have to write new task for it.

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)"
      DestinationFiles="$(DestinationFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"
      ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

Check all available [MSBuild metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx).

Comment: We are creating our own c# task, and want to make use of Copy from within that.  It looks as if this isnt possible, but I cant post an answer to my own question for another 5 hours due to SO security restrictions