# Copy To Output Directory and preserve directory structure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, visual-studio-project

I have a rather weird project setup (maybe I just dont understand it well enough)
this happens to be the project if it helps https://github.com/domoticz/domoticz

This project is generally used on linux but they have an MSBuild folder with project setup. I was able to get it to compile just fine but i cant get it to debug because some of the files (the whole www folder for example) is really content that is needed by the exe. I found that I can add an entire folder as content by adding the following in to the project file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\www\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

This will copy all of the files in the WWW but it doesnt retain any of the folder structure. what i need is for it to keep the www and on. Is there a way I can do this within the project file rather than doing it as a build event?

Also because I dont really know what im looking at, i've been unable to find any documentation around this XML definition, can anyone provide a link or search term to find out more about the structure of these files?

Thanks

Comment: MsBuild has tasks like Copy which can be used copy a directory structure as shown in e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331202/128384, put that in a <Target  name="CopyMyFile" AfterTargets="Build"> tag in the project file and it will execute whatever is in the target after the rest of the build. Is that what you're looking for? Info on msbuild, start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637714.aspx

Comment: Hmm yeah I had come across similar things and I guess the part I dont understand is whats the difference between marking a project file as 'content' vs telling the build to copy it over.

Comment: Content is a list of items with metadata representing commonly used options for copying and it's special in that it's recognized by the core of the build system. All so that you don't have to manually edit the project file since it will do the copy for you automatically. Well, excpect when Content doesn't cut it fo course :P https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx